# convert into date with R

Tags: r, as.date

```
> date<-as.character(date)
> head(date)
[1] "14-Jan" "14-Jan" "14-Jan" "14-Jan" "14-Jan" "14-Jan"
> date1<-as.Date(date,format="%y-%b")
> head(date1)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I wanna convert the date into date format so that i can make a extensible time series data.

Comment: you could add a day, e.g. `as.Date("14-Jan-01", "%y-%b-%d")`

Comment: > as.Date("14-Jan",format="%y-%b-%d")
[1] NA
> as.Date("14-Jan",format="%y-%b")
[1] NA         still cannot

Comment: hmmm, you didn't change anything in your comment above :)

Comment: The 'yearmon' class is available in the 'zoo' package. Several worked examples are available with the simple act of searching SO or Rhelp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Scott mentions, you may need to add the day value. Here is another way with `paste` (assumes the 1st day of the month for all entries):

```
date <- as.character(c("14-Jan", "14-Jan", "14-Jan", "14-Jan", "14-Jan", "14-Jan"))
date1 <- as.Date(paste0(date, "-1"),format="%y-%b-%d")
head(date1)
#[1] "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01"
```

you could then go back to displaying a year-month format in the following way:

```
format(date1, format="%y-%b")
#[1] "14-Jan" "14-Jan" "14-Jan" "14-Jan" "14-Jan" "14-Jan"
```

Comment: You could use `substr` to cut out the day: `date1 <- substr(as.Date(paste0(date, "-1"),format="%y-%b-%d"),1,7)`